Gibbs Free Energy and Definitions of Entropy
When we speak about entropy, it's classically defined as
$\delta S = \frac {\delta Q}{T}$
Where, I emphasize that it's the definition for only a change in entropy and not entropy itself (That's how I understood it).
And now, while speaking of the Gibbs Free Energy in Thermodynamics, I understand it as a measure of the total energy that can be extracted from a thermodynamic entity. Now, the first term in its definition accounts for the inherent energy i.e. the $U$ term (which I suppose comes from the internal thermal motion of the entity's molecules). The second term accounts for the work done on the entity i.e. the $pV$ term (energy transferred to the entity) to give it a finite volume.
Now, my confusion is with the third term, i.e. $TS$.
I suppose this definition encompasses the entropy term in its classical view because it is related to Temperature and in the Boltzmann definition, I suppose that it isn't explicitly related to Temperature.
But classically, I think, we could define only a change in entropy and not entropy itself. So what does the $S$ factor mean here? Is it Boltzmann Entropy or Classical Entropy?
If this definition is classical, then shouldn't the term actually be something like $\int T.\delta S$ with some limits thrown in because I suppose Temperature is a function of Entropy.
Where am I going wrong with these fundamentals? Also, are the two definitions of Entropy equivalent? If so, give me some helpful intuition.

According to Wikipedia, "The Gibbs free energy change $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S$ is the maximum amount of non-volume expansion work that can be extracted from a closed system (one that can exchange heat and work with its surroundings, but not matter) at fixed temperature and pressure." So there is a $\Delta S$ in there.

But that's for the change in GFE. My question is about the Absolute Gibbs Free Energy.

There is no absolute Gibbs Free Energy but there is absolute entropy that is accounted for (not quite measured) from $T=0$. Internal energy, Helmholtz free energy, Gibbs free energy, these are not "absolute", but entropy is absolute at T=0, this is more less the meaning of the 3rd "law". Even entropy's spatial distribution, that is entropy density, of an electromagnetic system is absolute unlike its energy density to which you can always add an an arbitrary source free static term, etc. without changing anything physical.

The Gibbs free energy is fundamentally defined by a Legendre transform of the enthalpy,
$$G=H-TS$$
The reason for this definition is that under conditions of constant composition the total differential $dG$ expands nicely to,
$$dG = VdP - SdT $$
This tells us that $G$ is an intrinsic function of $P$ and $T$, which differs from the other thermodynamic potentials like internal energy or enthalpy. It can be shown with a little extra effort that the change in Gibbs free energy is equivalent to the amount of non-$PV$ work that a system is capable of performing throughout a process. This is much closer to where you were starting from, but the fundamental definition of $G$ is a thermodynamic state function depending on $P$ and $T$ (and number of moles of each substance).
As an aside, entropy is one of the special thermodynamic quantities that actually can be explicitly defined unambiguously due to the 3rd Law. So there is no issue there.

It would be nicer if you put it in non technical terms as I'm a just a highschooler :)

I’m sorry you found this too high level. You were using inexact differentials (the Clausius definition of entropy), and the relationship of Gibbs free energy to work. Since I am not sure of your exact background I cannot really tune my answer to suit you any better.  Thermodynamics is an extremely technical subject, and failing to be at least a little technical just gets you in trouble with sloppy analogies and imprecise definitions.

So to have a systematic study of these fundamentals, what should I do? Could you recommend me some beginner friendly starting resources that deal with Entropy and minimize my misconceptions about Entropy? I'm helpless in a way that I can't even ask it on a Physics Educators StackExchange. I find Wikipedia to be so high level (technical) and unsuitable for a beginner like me. I expect crisp resources as I'm studying Thermodynamics outta only my own interest and I can't devote much time...

I would honestly suggest that you leave in depth study of thermodynamics until you get to a modern physics course or the equivalent in college. You are very unlikely to have the math background for it to make sense while you are in high school. You might learn some basics, like the fact that Gibbs free energy can predict spontaneity of chemical reactions or that entropy is directly related to the number of ways you can arrange a system (Microstates), but I doubt the multi variable calculus needed even for the definitions I gave will make sense for you yet.

Actually, I know a bit of multivariate calculus and partial differentiation. I'm fine with vector fields and stuff. I found the book by Enrico Fermi today and it was nice but I needed more problems. I think (though I ain't sure), I actually understood the partial differential in your equation above and that you've ignored the pdV term (when you take the differential with holding pressure as a constant) as dV is equal to zero

I did not ignore a term. I just skipped the steps of actually deriving the form of the total differential from the fundamental thermodynamic relation for internal energy.
